# Cakephp, i18n, SQL Error, Not unique table/alias

Tags: sql, cakephp, internationalization

I get the following SQL error:

```
SQL Error: 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'I18n__name'
```

when doing a simple find query.

Any ideas on possible situations that may have caused this??
I'm using a bindModel method to retrieve the data is that related?

This is my code:

```
$this->Project->bindModel(array(
                                        'hasOne' => array(
                                        'ProjectsCategories',
                                        'FilterCategory' => array(
                                                                'className' => 'Category',
                                                                'foreignKey' => false,
                                                                'conditions' => array('FilterCategory.id = ProjectsCategories.category_id')
                                                                ))));
$prlist = $this->Project->find('all', array(
                                                    'fields' => array('DISTINCT slug','name'),
                                                    'conditions' => array('FilterCategory.slug !='=>'uncategorised')
                                                    ))
```

Comment: What's your 'simple find query'?

Answer (score 1):

You have not used or initialized the required table/model you are using in your controller. Use `var $uses = array('your_table_name');`

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a direct answer to my problem. However after some research I came to the following conclusion.

I've decided to change my methodology and stop using the translate behavior in cakephp. 
I've found another behavior called i18n which works much better when dealing with associated models. You can read about it [http://www.palivoda.eu/2008/04/i18n-in-cakephp-12-database-content-translation-part-2/#comment-1380](http://here)
In cakephp book it says :

> "Note that only fields of the model
>   you are directly doing `find` on will
>   be translated. Models attached via
>   associations won't be translated
>   because triggering callbacks on
>   associated models is currently not
>   supported."

I'm not sure if I made the right choice however I have been struggling to get the translate behavior to work in cakephp and this solution at least makes the project I'm working functional.